# Theta joins associativtiy

Tags: database, join

I was studying  the query equivalence rules and encountered a rule that told that the ***theta joins*** are associative:

```
(E1 JOIN(c1) E2) JOIN(c2 and c3) E3 = E1 JOIN(c1 and c3) (E2 JOIN(c2) E3)
```

> c2 involves attributes from only E2 and E3.

It really looks perplexing and I am unable to grab the intuition. Thanks for reading.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: I am not getting concept clearly. What is the intuition behind this rule? That's my concern.

Comment: I think you will have more success on SO if you translate your (pseudo?) code/algebra into SQL code with sample data and expected results.